# Display data in internal storage in a vertical list

Tags: android

I am creating an app whereby I store input from edittext and spinner into internal storage. I have used MODE_APPEND so that information stored is not overridden. However it is stored horizontally despite me changing the XML orientation to vertical. How do I overcome that problem?

Portion of MainActivity:

```
    public void Save (View view){
    // add-write text into file

    // add-write text into file
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
        outputWriter.write(edDate.getText().toString());
        outputWriter.close();

        //display file saved message
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile2.txt", MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
        outputWriter.write(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        outputWriter.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

RecordDisplay.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".recordsdisplay"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Date:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Results:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewResults"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

RecordDisplay.java

```
    TextView date,Results;
FileInputStream fileInputStream;
static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recordsdisplay);
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    Results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResults);



    try {
            FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
            InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

            char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            String s="";
            int charRead;

            while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                // char to string conversion
                String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                s +=readstring;
            }
            InputRead.close();
            date.setText("Date:" +s);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
        FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile2.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

        char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String b="";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
            // char to string conversion
            String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
            b +=readstring;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        Results.setText("Results:" + b);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }







}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0capz.png)

Comment: You should use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` instead of a bunch of `TextView`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout`. This has the limitation that your XML file must define the exact number of rows when you make the app. If the user can add data and as many rows as she wishes, you should use `ListView` or `RecyclerView` instead. For other layout options check out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.